# Energy Lost on CPU Propagation Delay

Tags: cpu

I was wondering if anyone had some statistics about the average amount of energy that is lost on the process of propagation delay in moving a signal from one place on the CPU to another. I'd prefer statistics on modern CPUs, but I suppose any would be instructive.

Comment: check this article, its references might lead you to what you are looking for: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_power_dissipation

Comment: I used to have this sort of information to hand - it's some quantity of picojoules, with a very high variance; but what would you do with it?